# error: unknown filesystem linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub

Я хотел установить себе Linux рядом с Windows. У меня один ssd. Я разделил его на две части. Установка Linux не удалась, и я решил ее удалить. (Установка Linux была завершена на выделенном мною месте). Я просто загрузился в windows и отформатировал часть диска с помощью linux. После одной перезагрузки[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33vr.jpg) компьютер загрузился здесь (на фото), и я ничего не могу с этим поделать. Я не могу решить проблему с помощью "ls". Я не могу войти в биос[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: >Я просто загрузился в windows и отформатировал часть диска с помощью linux.

Это как так - то?

Comment: В смысле? Через дисковую утилиту в windows..

Comment: теперь нужно восстановить загрузчик windows... на системах до EFI это делалось загрузкой с установочного диска, запуском консоли управления и командами `fixboot` и `fixmbr`... на системах с EFI - хз... советаю обратится к гуглу с запросом «восстановить загрузчик windows», чтобы понимать, что делаешь...

Comment: s/консоли управления/консоли восстановления/

Comment: Я полностью удалил весь раздел с линуксом. У меня есть доступ к парочке команд по типу ls.